# How to view Center-Aligned PWM on an Oscilloscope

Tags: pwm

I wonder how can I identify if I see a PWM waveform on an oscilloscope screen whether it is an edge-aligned or a center-aligned PWM waveform. Can anyone help me how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Edge-aligned or center-aligned to what?

Comment: if you see this picture it will clear the point. [link](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kerhuel.eu%2Fw%2Fimages%2F6%2F6e%2FBlock_PWMMotor_Illustration_Centered.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicproducts.com%2FPower_Products%2FPower_Management%2FSmart_PWM_Modules_Simplify_Control_Run_Independent_Of_Core.aspx&docid=P74144e1AtWOPM&tbnid=EttIfkATzNzXaM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwimxZni8IngAhV4ShUIHfVAA_4QMwg-KAMwAw..i&w=600&h=458&bih=648&biw=1304&q=center%20aligned%20edge%20aligned%20pwm&ved=0ahUKEwimxZni8IngAhV4ShUIHfVAA_4QMwg-KAMwAw&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Comment: Are you attempting to identify a single waveform without referencing it to others? That is, are you attempting to look at a single trace on the scope and say, "That's center-aligned/edge-aligned"?

Comment: yes, i have 1 single pwm.. how can i identify it if it is edge or center aligned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write some code to flip back and forth on successive PWM cycles between two PWM values, say 10% and 50%. Typically you'd use an interrupt for that.

If the centers are equally spaced on successive pulses, it's center-aligned. If the spacing alternates between large and small it's edge aligned.

You can't tell the difference by looking at it outputting a single PWM value, because you usually have no available reference edge to compare it to.

Comment: Even better if you can output two simultaneous pwm signals and put them on different scope channels, too.

Comment: This is a fabulous answer. The flip idea is thinking outside the box!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you don't have access to the source code otherwise you could simpy read the datasheet for the chip that is generating the PWM signal and see if it's configurated for center or side alignment.

Also I suppose that by some mean the pwm ratio is changing or you can make-it change.

Ok, syncronise the oscilloscope on the rising edge and focus on the next rising edge. If there is no jitter on pwm ratio change then you have a side aligned pwm (starting wit a "1"). If you see a jitter then change to the falling edge and focus on the next falling edge. Again, if there is no jitter on PWM ratio change then you have a side aligned PWM (starting with a "0").

Otherwise you have a center aligned PWM.

For side aligned PWM you have always the same distance from the starting edge to the ending edge since the PWM cycle is constant while on center aligned PWM you will have a part of the  current cycle and a part of the next cycle. If the ratio varies between the two you will be able to see a jitter.